# Sharepoint 2013: how to clone a file within the current library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

Is there an easy way to clone a file WITHIN the current document library?  All my google searches show me how to copy to another library or copy the entire document library, but strangely enough, I cannot find a quick way to clone a file within the library.  Ideally, I would just like that everything is cloned and a new file name is provided as in the Windows standard xxx.docx=> xxx-Copy(2).docx or something similar.

Currently, as a workaround, I am downloading the file and then uploading it again.

Is there an easy solution for this or a web part/addin or some simple Sharepoint Designer code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of downloading the file then upload it again, you can use `Open With Explorer` option

[image]

- From the above ribbon, Click on `Open With Explorer`.
- Copy the required file and Paste it, then rename it as you prefer or leave it with the automated name.

> If the `Open With Explorer` option is disabled, check [We’re having a
>   problem opening this location in File Explorer, Add this website to
>   your Trusted sites list and try again](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the site in Internet Explorer. From Ribbon choose to Open In Explorer.

Copy and Paste the required files. If file exists it automatically renames to ..Copy..

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. As you are downloading and uploading, instead you can copy and paste like windows:
Please check 'Explorer View' (hope you are aware about this). This will open the library in Windows Explorer.
  **Requirement is** that you need to open document library in 'Internet Explorer' and 'Web Client' service should be running.
**Steps are:**
Open document library -> on top, click on Library tab -> Click on 'Open in Explore'
Hope this will help.
Apart from this you can do C# coding etc.

Answer (score 0):

With modern browsers (Edge, Chrome...) Open in Windows Explorer button is disabled but you can copy the url of the library (strip out the Forms/[view name].aspx from it) in your Windows file explorer and the result will be the same.

Another quick way is to use the "Email a Link" button in the library tab. It will open a mail with the link and you will just have to copy/paste it in File Explorer.